# scrollbar css for firefox in angularjs project

Tags: html, css, angularjs

My requirement is : I have angular project but custom scrollbar not appear in firefox, I added library simplebar css and simplebar js from github, could not fix it? Does any one know how to do this?

My code is :

```css
.simplebar {
  overflow: scroll;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 75px);
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 75px);
  height: calc(100% - 75px);
  position: absolute;
}
.simplebar-scrollbar,
[data-simplebar-direction] {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  /* Trigger native scrolling for mobile,  if not supported, plugin is used. */
}
.simplebar-scrollbar .simplebar-scroll-content,
[data-simplebar-direction] .simplebar-scroll-content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  /* hide browser scrollbar on IE10+ */
}
/* hide browser scrollbar on Webkit (Safari & Chrome) */

.simplebar-scroll-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
[data-simplebar-direction="horizontal"] .simplebar-scroll-content,
.simplebar.horizontal .simplebar-scroll-content {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.simplebar-scrollbar-track {
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 11px;
}
.simplebar-strack .simplebar-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  min-height: 10px;
  width: 7px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
  background: #6c6e71;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
}
.simplebar-track:hover .simplebar-scrollbar {
  /* When hovered, remove all transitions from drag handle */
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0 linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0 linear;
  -o-transition: opacity 0 linear;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0 linear;
  transition: opacity 0 linear;
}
.simplebar-track .simplebar-scrollbar.visible {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
[data-simplebar-direction="horizontal"] .simplebar-track,
.simplebar.horizontal .simplebar-track {
  top: auto;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 11px;
}
[data-simplebar-direction="horizontal"] .simplebar-track .simplebar-scrollbar,
.simplebar.horizontal .simplebar-track .simplebar-scrollbar {
  right: auto;
  top: 2px;
  height: 7px;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 10px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<!--<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="vendor/jquery - 1.10.2.min.js "><\/script>')</script>-->
<script src="simplebar.js"></script>
<script src="simpebar.min.js"></script>


<div class="simplebar">
  <!--Start SCROLL BAR, Div Added/Edited by VIKAS GAYAKWAD -->
  <ul class="media-list">
    <contact-card data-client="client" ng-repeat="client in clientList"></contact-card>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--End SCROLL BAR--->
```

Comment: Can you please format that CSS, so hard to read.

Comment: hi Zze i have edited css.

Comment: I assume you are including the CSS file, and just left it out of the question code `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/simplebar.css" />` . Also, you are including both the minified version and normal version of simplebar.js, maybe they are overwriting one another?

Comment: hey Zze its angular project i added styles sheet in main css..